# Magento.default time zone UTC

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, cron

I see Magento use UTC time zone by default. Its a problem for my cron tasks. 
But for all stores i have set my current time zone but UTC still using.
How to set time zone without changing Mage.php or another core file ?

Comment: you need to set time zone for your store

Answer (score 2):

Goto

> Admin panel > System> Configuratin > General > Locale Option

You can set different timezone for each store

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Magento internally "normalises" all timestamps to UTC. That's why the `created_at/updated_at` dates you see in the database are consistent.

You don't give any info regarding what the problem is with your cron jobs (are you using magento or standalone php scripts??) but if you're dealing with timestamps you should be using `\Mage_Core_Model_Locale::storeTimeStamp()`

or if you need to check if the current time is within a range use `\Mage_Core_Model_Locale::isStoreDateInInterval()`

Good luck!

PS: there are other methods in that class that you'll find useful.